# In java web application how to translate list of country name from english to arabic in a drop down field of jsp page?

Tags: java, jquery, spring, jsp

I want to display country names in arabic language(java web application) .The country names are loaded from the database(name are in English). Can any one help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

For translation you should need API to do this. i know google does this and they may also give this API to use.

Check this link. It may help you.

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/source/browse/trunk/src/test/TranslateTest.java?r=49

Comment: uvvu....exact link :)